# Is it possible to access static variable from another translation unit?

Tags: c++, static

a1.cpp

```
static int a = 20;
```

a2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern int a;

int main() {
  std::cout<<a<<std::endl;  // link error
}
```

If you can't modify a1.cpp, is it possible to change a2.cpp so that it can visit `a` in a1.cpp? Maybe using assembly?

------- EDIT ---------

Just in case someone interested, I finally found a way to do it:

a1.cpp

```
static int a = 20;
```

a2.cpp

```
int b = 100;

int main() {
    int* p = &b;
    p--;
    *p = 42;  // now a in a1.cpp is changed from 20 to 42, tested by clang++ 3.8.1

    return 0;
}
```

I know this is not the reason for `static`, just curious if we can use address and offset to hack it.

Comment: You mean `static` qualified variables or variables with _static_ storage duration in general? And don't spam tags.

Comment: You can modify a static object from another translation unit if you have a pointer to it.

Comment: Global variables marked with `static` have *internal linkage* meaning they are not exported from the translation unit. If you need to access it from another translation unit the variable needs to have *external linkage* (which is the default for non-static global variables.).

Comment: What is unclear about `static` qualified variables having **internal** linkage?

Comment: If you want to reference `a` from another compilation unit, why make it `static` in the first place?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Someone mentioned that there is a way called `hook` or something similar to visit static variable in another translation unit, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Deqing That's not really a reason for the `static`, isn't it?

Comment: A "hook" is basically a callback-function. If the function being called (the *hook*) is in the same translation unit then it can of course use the static variable. Or if the hook function is passed a copy of the variable then you can access its value (but not change it). Or if the hook function is passed a pointer to the variable, then you can change the variable as well (emulating pass by reference).

Comment: If you are generating ELF objects (with _GCC_ for example) you could compile a1.cpp to an object file and use _objcopy_ to mark the static variable `a` in a1.cpp as global which would make it visible to other objects during link time. This is probably not what you had in mind, but thought I'd mention it. Of course I'd wonder why you are doing all this, and what problem you are trying to solve. Why mark something `static` if you intend for it to be global.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is `static` in `a1.cpp` then only `a1.cpp` can access it *directly*, it cannot be accessed by other units with `extern` at all.

Assembly *can* access it, but *only* if you know the variable's memory address at runtime.

In general, `a1.cpp` would have to pass a pointer to the variable to `a2.cpp` (in which case assembly is not needed). But if you cannot change `a1.cpp` to do that then you are pretty much out of luck, unless the variable happens to have a unique value that you can scan memory for.  That is not not likely, though.